# How can I reinstall Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading, system-error

I was having some issues with my samsung galaxy s2. I took it to an I.T. store to get it fixed and now all is working fine, except play store is no longer there. I went into 'all applications' in settings and  play store is not there either so there is no way for me to set it back up. When I try and download straight from the internet version of plays store, an error tells me I do not have a device. Can anyone please tell me what I can do to fix this or if there is any other way for me download apps such as facebook and snapchat? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, if you'd like then you can also get the Google PlayStore apk file from [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com) over [apkmirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-1-11-apk/) if you'd like ! And rest I can see that query has already been answered !

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can install all your applications via their **.apk** package, downloadable from the internet (you'll also find several alternative markets like aptoide and F-Droid).
As of play store: the website only tells the android app to install a certain app, so if you don't have it installed, you won't go any further.

1. install play store via it's .apk  [there](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1996995)
2. if, once it is installed, it opens and then closes immediately, it is possible that the company that fixed it flashed a firmware without it. In this case, you'll need to [flash the appropriate GApps package](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93591/how-can-i-reinstall-play-store)

PS: I highly recommend to flash gapps as most apps have google-modules dependencies (for instance google play services)

Answer (score 0):

There are many other android markets like 9apps,mobogenie,mobomarket etc and they work fine but if you compare to Google play store, they are a little bit lower. In case of restoring Google play store, download Google play store and check that the version is supported by your device or not. Or you can google about the version of play store your phone was having then download it from any website. If problem resists, then use titanium backup and get the backed up play store of any other device and place the backup in the titanium backup folder of the sdcard and then manually go to titanium backup and then restore it. You can also flash the Gapps again but this will reset your phone. So the great idea is to flash the Gapps or download straight the Google play store from the apk file. Try the newest version supported by your android.

Comment: You don't need root to install the Google Play Store apk file. Also, backing up system apps is not a great idea generally, flashing the Gapps Zip would be better in that case.